# Enabling hubsites in SharePoint 2019

Tags: modern-experience, 2019, hub-site

I am working with SP 2019 on prem. I know that modern ui is available in sp 2019 on prem, is there a way to enable hubsites via powershell for on prem 2019? If someone has done it, please share, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Server 2019 does not have hub sites nor will it. SharePoint Server 2019 is a 'snapshot in time' with certain features adjusted/removed from SharePoint Online -- SharePoint Online did not have hub sites at the time the snapshot was taken.